# Set FormType's option dynamically, based on the data of a sibling FormType?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I have a Symfony Form with a custom ChoiceType that needs to filter the available choices, based on the value of another field (a sibling form-type inside the same form).

I am using EasyAdmin CMS that doesn't allow its fields to pass down additional *dynamic* `type_options` to their form-types, [because of it YAML configuration](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/2983). And I'd like the the custom ChoiceFormType to have encapsulate the logic on how to resolve its own options.

### But modifying the options based on other form data seems impossible.

- form data is `NULL` inside `buildForm()`; I can access it just from `FormEvents`.
- inside `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` I cannot replace the current type with one having the modified options.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder, $options) {
        $parent = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        $parent_data = $parent-getData();
        $other_field_value = $parent_data->getOtherFieldValue();
        $filtered_choices = array_filter(fn($choice) => $choice !== $other_field_value);
        $options['choices'] = $filtered_choices;

        $parent->add($form, get_class($this), $options);   // THIS FAILS
    }
```

Trying to set the options, resolved dynamically based on the form data, fails with:

> A cycle was detected. Listeners to the PRE_SET_DATA event must not call setData(). You should call setData() on the FormEvent object instead.

But the `$event->setData()` works just on the current FormType, not on the the whole form.

#### *What's the pattern to make a FormType set its own options dynamically, based on the value of a sibling form type?*

Comment: Wich version of easyadmin do you use ? The third one is no more using YAML, maybe you should switch to easyadmin 3 to handle this ?

Comment: I use EasyAdmin 2.5 and I cannot upgrade yet to 3.0.

Comment: Hi, yours is not an actual StackOverflow Answer. For requesting details on StackOverflow you should use the comments section of the Question (see my comment above).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29290037)

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? There is a symfonycast with this issue and they solve it only with symfony (without easyadmin) but it is too difficult to convert it to easyadmin.

Comment: EasyAdmin is too inflexible. It doesn't allow control on Form generation (except on the default CRUD actions); iirc, in `EasyAdminFormType` everything is packed in a single function of a `final` class: the opposite of ideal; can't inject data before processing. You'd need to override the whole class, write your own implementation, inject it and make it used by EasyAdmin (but, iirc, it was a pain to make even that). Maybe there's is a way, but I coulnd't find any, got frustrated, abandoned the feature (luckily wasn't required). I don't know how to help you here sorry.

Comment: Would you please add the link to the SymfonyCast you mentioned?